# Is Colorama required for Flask or Click?

Tags: python, flask, colorama

I'm trying to do the Flask "Hello World" tutorial and when I do the 'flask run' command on terminal I get the following traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\boymeetscode\PycharmProjects\beerRPG> flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\Scripts\flask-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 990, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 596, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 844, in run_command
    show_server_banner(get_env(), debug, info.app_import_path, eager_loading)
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 678, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(f" * Environment: {env}")
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 294, in echo
    file = auto_wrap_for_ansi(file)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\boymeetscode\miniconda3\envs\beerRPG\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 541, in auto_wrap_for_ansi
    import colorama
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
```

I am on Windows, Python 3.9.7 and did the `pip install flask` in my venv so if colorama is a dependency I would expect that it would have been installed automatically. Why isn't it?

Update: I manually installed colorama and now Flask works. I'm just still confused why if this is a dependency it wasn't installed automatically. My pip install didn't appear to return any errors.

Comment: AFAIK, flask requires click, then click requires colorama (https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/main/setup.py). Did the `pip install flask` complete without errors? Can you [edit] to post the output of `pip list` after installation? Also, [edit] to post your python version and flask version.

Comment: What Flask version did you install when the error happened? I have no Windows machine to confirm/verify, but it seems Flask 8.0.0 fixes the problem by auto-installing colorama on Windows: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/changes/?highlight=colorama#version-8-0-0: "*Colorama is always installed on Windows in order to provide style and color support.* [#1784](https://github.com/pallets/click/pull/1784)")

Comment: The flask version is 2.0.1 but the click is 8.0.1. Colorama is not being automatically installed on windows. I just tested it again with a fresh instance. Maybe this is a conda issue since I'm using that instead of venv?

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm something in conda or click broke recently: colorama is missing after installing click (which was installed for [black](https://github.com/psf/black) in my case). I use conda environment files so instead of manually installing I added a more recent version with

```
  - conda-forge::click
```

in the .yml file.

Then `conda update` installed click 8.03 *and* colorama, over click 8.0.1 which I had. Without an env file `conda install -c conda-forge click` should do the trick.

I do not know what exactly fixed it though, it is not in [click's release notes](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/changes/#): though there was arecent change to always install colorama, that was in version 8.0.0.